# Nested IAsyncEnumerable memory leak

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks, async-await

I have the following code that causes a memory leak. When using an `await` inside two nested `IAsyncEnumerables`.

The Func `work` is a function that takes an input from the input channel and returns a `IAsyncEnumerable` which is iterated over an put into the output channel.

If i use one of the two lines marked with `// Works!` code runs as expected without building up a huge heap.

Looking at the memory profiler without the mem leak, everything looks normal the DTO(`TOut`) object `result` returned by the ´work´ enumeration is only referenced by the output channel as expected keeping a max of 10 as its bounded.

When running the code with the memory leak every DTO object from the `work` `IAsyncEnumerable` is kept in memory with a reference in the root path, to the `work` function and a reference to some static variable `Dictionary<Int32,Task> [Statis variable Task.s_currentActiveTasks]` its like the tasks generated by the IAsyncEnumerator are never completed and disposed of.

```
public static ChannelReader<TOut> Pipe<TIn, TOut>(this ChannelReader<TIn> input, Func<TIn, IAsyncEnumerable<TOut>> work, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
        var output = Channel.CreateBounded<TOut>(10);

        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await foreach (var item in input.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {                       
                    await foreach (var result in work(item))
                    {
                        // Memory leak!
                        await output.Writer.WriteAsync(result, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                        // Works!
                        //while (!output.Writer.TryWrite(result))
                        //    Thread.Sleep(1);
                        
                        // Works!
                        //output.Writer.WriteAsync(result, cancellationToken).AsTask().Wait(); 
                    }
                }

                output.Writer.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                output.Writer.Complete(ex);
            }
        });

        return output;
}
```

Can anyone shed some insight into this problem?

If someone can't spot something obvious wrong that I've missed, I'll try and post a minimum reproducible example. I don't have alot of experience yet with IAsyncEnumerable.

Comment: Note that `Task.s_currentActiveTasks` is used by the debugger only. Are you sure that your leak isn't caused by the debugger?

Comment: @canton7 No! i'm not. Thank you, will try it out now. I've found a issue with the debugger not closing tasks with IAsyncEnumerable but it should have been fixed.

Comment: @mjwills it appears it was the debugger. Running the code without the debugger attached solves the problem and everything works as expected with low memory footprint. See this issue https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/39321